# Firebase Filter by Date in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFTJj.jpg)

i want equivalent query like this for in Xamarin forms, for showing data between date range

```
firebase.database().ref().child("Users").orderByChild('regdate')
  .startAt("2019-01-05").endAt("2019-01-10");
```

or any other way to filter data by date range in xamrin forms. i am using NuGet package **FirebaseDatabase.net** for my app.
please help me how can i achieve it?

i copy the above query from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54171488/firebase-filter-by-date).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repo for the `firebase-database-dotnet` package contains documentation on [how to query the database](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet#querying). From reading that, it looks like the query you found translates to:

```
var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/");
var users = await firebase
  .Child("Users")
  .OrderBy("regdate")
  .StartAt("2019-01-05")
  .EndAt("2019-01-10")
  .OnceAsync<User>();
```

Where `User` is a custom class that you create to represent the JSON properties that you store for a user in the database, similar to the [`Dinosaur` class](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/blob/master/samples/Dinosaurs/Dinosaurs/Dinosaur.cs), [`Message` class](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/blob/master/samples/OfflineChat/OfflineChat/Message.cs), and [`Author` class](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/blob/master/samples/OfflineChat/OfflineChat/Author.cs) in the samples in the `firebase-database-dotnet` repo.

Comment: Frank its giving me error **Response: {
  "error" : "Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"DateCLD\", for path \"/Sales\", to the rules"
}**

Comment: i have also update my orignal Firebase database image.

Comment: You'll need to define an index in your security rules, so that the Firebase server can perform the query. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Comment: thank you Frank, after adding index i got the expecting output.

Comment: can you please also tell me how i can real time notify in xamarin forms when new data insert or data delete etc?

Comment: From a quick [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bxamarin%5D+realtime) it seems that ` .AsObservable<Dinosaur>().Subscribe(d => Console.WriteLine(d.Key));` are the way to do that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42965924/permitting-firebase-xamarin-realtime-streaming